# Forever stops after few hours without any error

Tags: node.js, forever

I Created one sockt.io application and running it using forever npm. Its working fine for few hours but after that its stops and there is no error in log file also.

I checked so many times and I am getting nothing.

Is there any issue in socket.io or forever.

Please help me

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('Server connected');
  //room connected
  socket.on('join', function(roomId){
    //join room
    socket.join(roomId);
  });

  //for new order
  socket.on('new_order', function(locationId){
    console.log("New order");
    socket.broadcast.to(locationId).emit('client_new_order', locationId);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
  forever start server.js // name of ur js file
```

After you start the server the name of log will and path will be mentioned, if any errors, then they are placed in this log file .

Comment: Sorry I checked all the options and its not working.

Comment: hit forever list

Comment: My issue is different. Its working for few hours then stops.

Comment: Will suggest you to try pm2 once

Comment: pm2 is solution or replacement?

Comment: Its npm module similar to forever, which is more faster and enhances performance and widely used. More better  than forever in performance
Its a replacement.